# Django error migrating nesting model w/o migrating base model

Tags: django, postgresql, model, migration, radix

Purpose to have one BaseModel that can be nested by other models

**NOTE:** BaseModel should not be written to database

So I have one BaseModel like below

```
class StaticVariable(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=250, blank=False, null=False
    )
    alias = models.CharField(
        max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False
    )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, blank=False, null=False
    )
    enabled = models.BooleanField(
        default=True, blank=False, null=False
    )
    deleted = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, blank=False, null=False
    )
```

I made migrations and applied it, since class Meta has **managed=False** parameter, actual SQL table is not being created (**as expected**)

After that I create new model which is being nested from **StaticVariable** model as base

```
class BodyType(StaticVariable):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'body_type'
        ordering = ["title", "-id"]
```

Then I makemigrations, which looks like this

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('utils', '0004_staticvariable'),
        ('app', '0002_alter_category_enabled'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BodyType',
            fields=[
                ('staticvariable_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='utils.staticvariable')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'body_type',
                'ordering': ['title', '-id'],
            },
            bases=('utils.staticvariable',),
        ),
    ]
```

But, unexpectedly I catch below error when I try to migrate

```
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0003_bodytype...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 737, in execute
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "utils_staticvariable" does not exist
```

I suppose that this is because BaseModel wasn't written to the DB, but I don't want to write empty table to DB

Comment: Try `abstract = True` instead of `managed = False` and run the migrations.

Comment: Thank you @MohammadGolamDostogir , you sugestion worked, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Great. Thank you. I have posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inherit from a model Django by default sets up a `one-to-one` relationship with the base model, which is why it's trying to create a `staticvariable_ptr` field in your `BodyType` model that points to a `StaticVariable` instance.

As in your code `StaticVariable` has `managed = False`, Django doesn't manage the database table for this model, which leads to the error you are facing.

To solve the issue you should use abstract base classes (Ref. [Django Abstract Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes))

You define an abstract base class by setting `abstract = True` in the Meta class of `StaticVariable` model like this:

```
class StaticVariable(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

After making these changes make sure to make new migrations and migrate.